# C macro for protobuf message comparison

Tags: c++, macros, protocol-buffers, proto3

My goal is to compare some fields in protobuf messages. I have tried MessageDifferencer, but I don't want to use reflection. I'm using protobuf 3.4.0.

Time variables are stored in protobuf's well-known types like google.protobuf.Duration and google.protobuf.Timestamp.

I would like to use a macro which takes two objects and a field name:

```
CHECK_GPS_TIME ( expectedGps, storedGps, gps_time );
```

I'm expecting the following result:

```
CHECK ( expectedGps.gps_time().seconds() == storedGps.gps_time().seconds() );
```

I already have a macro for simple types:

```
#define CHECK_GPS_FIELD(expected, stored, field) CHECK( expected.field() == stored.field() );
```

Comment: what is the question/problem?

Comment: I would like to ask some help how to paste more function names (in this case ".seconds()") after the field.

Comment: My first guess would be:
    #define CHECK_GPS_TIME (expected, stored, field) CHECK_GPS_FIELD( expected, stored, field##.seconds())

Comment: why is `GPS_TIME` part of the macro name when you also pass `gps_time` as parameter?

Comment: I'm using catch.hpp where CHECK macro is already defined.

Comment: to be honest I dont really understand what would be the benefit if you can write `CHECK_GPS_TIME ( expectedGps, storedGps, gps_time );` instead of `CHECK ( expectedGps.gps_time().seconds() == storedGps.gps_time().seconds() );`. Anyhow, you should include your first guess and the error messages into the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167091/discussion-between-jonas-balazs-and-user463035818).